# Optimal covering trails in 3 and 4 dimensions

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, lattices, covering

A couple of years ago, I constructively solved (inside the $AABB$  $[0,3]$ X $[0,3]$ X ... X $[0,3]$) the $k$-dimensional generalization of the infamous Nine-Dot Problem by S. Loyd (see *Cyclopedia of puzzles*, p. 301 (1914)), which asks to find the minimum link covering trail (i.e., a polygonal chain of minimum size) that visits all the $3^k$ points of the set $G_{3,k}:=${$0,1, 2$} X {$0,1, 2$}} X ... X {$0,1, 2$} in $R^k$.

Unfortunately, I was not able to achieve the same result with the following couple of $3D$ and $4D$ foundamental grids:
$G_{4,3}:=${$0,1, 2, 3$} X {$0,1, 2, 3$}} X {$0,1, 2, 3$} and $G_{2,4}:=${$0,1$} X {$0,1$} X {$0,1$} X {$0,1$}.

In 2013, it has been proved by Keszegh that the minimum link covering trail for $G_{n,2}$ has size $2*(n-1)$ for any $n>2$ and it is also known that the minimum link covering trail for $G_{2,3}$ has size $6$ (i.e., we can join the $8$ vertices of any cube with a polygonal chain of size $6$, even under the additional constraint of using only line segments of the same length).

It follows that the solution for $G_{2,4}$ have to be at most equal to $13$.
On the other hand, years ago, I proved that the minimum link covering trail for $G_{4,3}$ has size between $21$ and $23$.

Is it possible to improve any of the provided bounds for these tricky *thinking outside the box* brain teasers?

Comment: Loyd's puzzle can be seen at https://www.mathpuzzle.com/loyd/cop300-301.html

Comment: Are you Marco Ripa, of Ripa and Remirez, The nine dots puzzle extended to $n\times n\times\cdots\times n$ points, available via the Citeseer site? That Marco has several other papers cited at https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Cyclopedia-of-puzzles-Loyd/082b4d6f781ebe11100e30f19d205fa56af359d4

Comment: Basically, the 3 x 3 x ... x 3 solution (in R^k) I was talking about is (3^k-1)/2 links and it can be found here: [Solving the 106 years old 3^k points problem with the Clockwise-Algorithm](https://ejournal2.undip.ac.id/index.php/jfma/article/download/8551/4813) (DOI: https://doi.org/10.14710/jfma.v3i2.8551);
while the 2 x 2 x 2 optimal covering trails are given in this paper [General uncrossing covering paths inside the Axis-Aligned Bounding Box](https://ejournal2.undip.ac.id/index.php/jfma/article/download/12053/6717):
(DOI: https://doi.org/10.14710/jfma.v4i2.12053).

Comment: Now, speaking about planar grids (which would be a different topic), the cited viXra manuscript was a very bad (embarassing) preprint: it was written because, as an asperger, I couldn't sleep struggling with some kind of brain teaser and I didn't know anything about the research on this topic at the time. It took me several years to solve the 3 x 3 x ... x 3 family.
Anyway, I can tell you that I am almost ended an ultimate paper for the n x n family, citing, proving, generalizing and extending many valuable conjectures that I've recently found on MathPuzzle (a wonderful web resource, indeed).